# Angularjs auto-hide navigation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

i would like to make my navigation menu that is fixed to the top of my page to auto-hide the same way you can make the taskbar in windows hide when you have "auto-hide taskbar" enabled

I would like it to hide and then when you move your mouse close to the top of the screen for it to become visible again and then hide again when you move your mouse away from the top.

What is the best way i can make this happen?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many different ways to do this but a very quick think about it ...

You have your HTML nav bar...

```
<div nav-directive>
  <div class="nag" ng-class="{ 'visible': visible }"></div>
</div>
```

Directive

```
.directive('navDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA', 
    link: function(scope, el) {
      scope.visible = false;

      el.bind('mouseover', function() {
         scope.visible = true;
         // You shouldn't do but may need a scope apply here, not sure... 
      });

      el.bind('mouseout', function() {
        scope.visible = false;
        // again not sure scope apply?
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This will get you your basic adding and removing the class `visible`.

Then you can use some CSS3 to get some sliding motion in.

```
.nav {
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.nav.visible {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful, but when it moves up, its not possible to move the mouse onto it to reveal it again as it isn't within the frame of the window anymore, i solved this by moving it up 80% and leaving a small portion for the user to move the mouse onto. but ideally i would like it to reveal itself when the user places the mouse on the area where it would have been if it where visible. But none the less, i found this helpful and it is working alright for me